# Segmentation Fault on mplayer and mpv

Tags: linux, debian, debug

I'm trying to run `mplayer` or `mpv` on my Raspberry Pi, but even after multiple `apt-get remove`s and even `apt-get install --reinstall`s, I'm still getting the annoyingly undetailed `Segmentation fault` error message, even though other packages like `vlc` and `aplayer` work just fine.

I have the `stretch` repo in my `sources.list`, but the default repo is `jessie`. How can I get the `mplayer`/`mpv` to work on my device?

I don't think it's my SD Card's problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the annoyingly undetailed Segmentation fault error message

If this is happening something is probably broken, and if you have really replaced the executable repeatedly, it is likely something it links to -- a library, but obviously not too critical a one or else you would be having this problem with other things as well (or, it could be the broken bit is in a common library, but it is an obscure bit).

By "broken" I mean the file has become corrupted. The only other possibility, since you are using stretch ("but the default repo is jessie") is it is some subtle mismatch in pieces that has gone unnoticed (which might happen particularly if it is a relatively unique mismatch of jessie and stretch pieces).

If you want to try tracking the problem down (and I cannot promise it will work), `apt install gdb`, then run `gdb mplayer`, it will take 10 seconds or so to get to a prompt, then enter `run ...` where `...` is the rest of the commandline you would usually use with `mplayer`.

When the segfault happens, the prompt will come back.  Type `bt` or `backtrace`.  The first time you do this, you may get a lot of `in ???`, but you may also get a message to install some debugging packages (I'm not positive the Debian/Raspbian version does this; if not things just got too complicated).  Unfortunately those can sometimes be quite large. You can then try the backtrace again and get more details.

If you edit that backtrace into your question I can hazard a guess at what is broken.

However, if this is happening more widely you might as well re-install; random corruption of system libraries is not something that can easily be fixed.

---

Another possibility, since `mpv` has the same problem, is to look at the output of `ldd $(which mplayer)` and `ldd $(which mpv`) and see what the **most obscure** things they have in common are (not `libc` or `libdl`, etc. -- again if you post this in the question I could hazard a guess).  You should then try replacing the packages that provide those libraries.  If you are not sure use the [Debian package contents search](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents).

Comment: Thank you for the well-written and through answer, using `ldd` and the `gdb` I managed to track down the misbehaving libraries, and reinstalled them from Jessie. The ones from the stretch seems to be the cause of the problem. Everything works great now!